# How do I pass a parameter to Primefaces menuitem that shows a dialog?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a p:menuButton which contains several p:menuitems. Each of these items has to calls a method with a certain parameter on the session scoped backing bean and open a modal dialog which depends on that backing bean. My p:menuitem looks like this:

```
<p:menuitem value="..." oncomplete="dialog.show()" update=":dialog" actionListener="#{myController.createNewItem}">
</p:menuitem>
```

The parameter passed to myController.createNewItem is the only thing that depends on which menuitem was clicked and I tried to pass it in 3 ways:

1) `<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myController.newItem.property}" value="..." />`

This doesn't work because modal dialog seems to block f:setPropertyActionListener. The setter for myController.newItem.property gets called only after I close the dialog, which is not good enough. It works if the dialog is not modal, but I really need it to be modal.

2) `<f:attribute name="param" value="..." />`
event.getComponent().getAttributes() returns a map with a single element, which looks something like some_namespace.MARK_ID => some number, which is clearly not the parameter I wanted to pass.

3) `<f:param name="param" value="..." />`
I read this works only with action, not actionListener, but tried it anyway.
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap() contains all the fields on my form as well as some extra parameters, but not the one I wanted to pass, so I guess it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do here or am I stuck with using f:setPropertyActionListener and non-modal dialog? Thanks.

Comment: how bout `actionListener="#{myController.createNewItem(your value)}"`

Comment: @Ravi No, it's not a duplicate as I already use update and oncomplete attributes.

Comment: @Daniel I read that passing parameters through expression is possible on for action, not for actionListener.

Comment: ya its not possible to pass parameters using actionListener. Try <p:ajax listener=""> it takes arguments.

Comment: @MilošRašić why don't your use action ? `public void createNewItem(.... `

Comment: I'm under impression that action does a submit and starts a new request while actionlistener does an ajax request. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm new to jsf.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pass argumens , just use `action`

```
<p:menuitem value="..." oncomplete="dialog.show()" update=":dialog" action="#{myController.createNewItem(your parameter)}">
</p:menuitem>
```

where `createNewItem`

```
public void createNewItem(.....){
}
```

or

```
public String createNewItem(.....){

     return null;
}
```

using `action` with `return null` or `void` wont do any navigation...

about the *ajax request* , `<p:menuitem` is doing `ajax` implicitly under the hood anyway

Comment: It will be attempted, Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p:menuitem value="menu item 1" update=":someForm:someJSFComponent" actionListener="#{myBean.myMethodItemListener}">
    <f:attribute name="theItem" value="#{itemValue}" />
</p:menuitem>



bean side:

public void myMethodItemListener(ActionEvent event) {
    itemSel = (SomeClassCasting) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("itemValue");
}
```

this works for me on my project:

```
<p:menuButton value="#{msg.curso}">
    <c:forEach items="#{cursoBean.cursos}" var="cursoItem">
        <p:menuitem value="#{cursoItem.nome}" update=":disciplinasForm:cursoSelLabel" actionListener="#{cursoBean.selecionaItemListener}">
            <f:attribute name="cursoItem" value="#{cursoItem}" />
        </p:menuitem>
    </c:forEach>
</p:menuButton>

public void selecionaItemListener(ActionEvent event) {
    itemSelecionado = (Curso) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("cursoItem");
}
```